# Php : get formData base64 image string and upload to local folder

Tags: php, mysql, reactjs, file-upload

I have base64 image string sending in my API calling to a `.php` file

Request URL :

```
http://localhost/server/index.php?saveImageToFolder=true?id=1&name=fdsfsdf
```

My HTML form looke like below

[image: htmlform]

Below is my code for sending base64 from Input type `file` which is in reactjs

```
function getBase64(file) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function () {
            resolve(reader.result);
        };
        reader.onerror = reject;
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    });
}

const onChangeImage = (e, id, slotname) => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', e.target.files[0]);

    const fileFound = e.target.type === 'file' && e.target.files[0];
    const promise = fileFound && getBase64(fileFound);

    promise.then(function(result) {
        uploadImage({ 'id': id, 'slotname': slotname, 'slotimage': result });
    })

    
}
```

And then i have `formData` in my payload. Below is the complete network tab payload

[image: httprequest]

My `index.php`

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");
include("connect.php");

error_reporting(0);
session_start();

if(isset($_GET['saveImageToFolder'])){
    var_dump($_POST['file']);  //This is showing NULL
    var_dump($_FILES['file']);  //This is also showing NULL
    
    $data = $_POST['file'];
    list($type, $data) = explode(';', $data);
    list(, $data)      = explode(',', $data);
    $data = base64_decode($data);
  
    file_put_contents('image.png', $data);
}
```

Image file is creating with `PNG` and 0KB. Not getting how to fetch values of `formData` and  then further in `index.php`

Comment: How are you sending the formData string exactly? Am guessing it's some JavaScript/ajax? Please show that

Comment: @ADyson i have updated my code. I'm using React to send `formData` through `post` call in `axios`

Comment: Thanks but it's incomplete, you forgot to show the uploadImage function

Comment: @ADyson `onChangeImage`  is where the upload happens. I have added this on file change

Comment: Yes but it calls a function called uploadImage() in order to actually send the data, and we don't know what that function does. There's nothing directly in the code you've shown which would cause an upload to occur.

Comment: BTW this bit of code: `const formData = new FormData(); formData.append('file', e.target.files[0]);` is pointless because you never use `formData` for anything. Instead you're using the `result` of the fileReader load event (which is probably fine, but it means the formData object you've created is redundant).

Comment: P.S. Have you tried var_dump($_POST); and var_dump($_FILES); to see if there's any data which isn't named with the values you're testing currently? Or what about `var_dump(file_get_contents("php://input"));` in case there's anything usable in the raw input stream?

Comment: P.P.S. Also, is there any particular reason you're choosing to use base64 to upload the file rather than a standard multipart request (i.e. sending the file as binary)?

Answer (score 0):

```
const fileFound = e.target.type === 'file' && e.target.files[0];
```

evaluates to true or false and in the next step you pass a boolean to `getBase64()` instead of the filename.

```
const promise = fileFound && getBase64(fileFound);
```

So change it to

```
const promise = fileFound && getBase64(file);
```

instead.